# Indonesia Level 3 Administrative Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, data, indonesia

I've been looking for Indonesia shapefile for level 3 or more administrative boundary and I still haven't found it yet.
I found in (gadm.org) but it only level 2.
So anyone know where I could find it?
I would prefer a single Indonesia shapefile instead of downloading each province shapefile one by one.
Also it would be great if it has properties like the name of the area, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it here just now:
https://ordercitrasatelit.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/free-peta-batas-administrasi-desa-seluruh-indonesia/

It is pretty detailed. It has up to level 4 administrative boundaries. Also it has area properties such as province, regency, kecamatan, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Also have a look at the OpenStreetMap based service by user wambacher:

https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/

try the tree menu on the left screen to choose boundaries to be exorted in different formats.

Be aware:

Pay attention to the free licence used by OSM,

and due to massive bulk downloads in the past  some big download queries need a login there via OAuth to an existing OSM account.

Answer (score -1):

numerous datasets available online.

[Data for Indonesia](https://revolutionarygis.wordpress.com/2015/01/17/batas-desa-shapefile/)

Comment: Would you please describe what the shapefiles you are offering are? and where the link is to get them? Also note that it is better to add the link with the link tool.